# How can I install an SSIS package in a SQL Server 2012 and not be upgraded automatically? Re: Error with version number

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I created a package in my workstation using Visual Studio 2010 for SQL Server 2012 (v 11.0.2100.60) with a format version 6 (I can check it in the DTSX file), but when I later deploy it on a SQL Server 2012 (v 11.0.7462.6) using the SQL Server Import/Export wizard in SQL Server Management Studio, somehow it gets upgraded to format version 8.

So I can't execute it because I get an error:

> Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number."

How can it automatically upgrade the package to a version it can't manage? Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you need Visual Studio 2012 or later to upgrade the package to the required version.

If you will (most likely) be using a later version of SSDT than 2012, pay attention to the compatibility level of the package, as VS will probably upgrade it to the latest SQL Server version it knows about.

Once you create a SSIS project, go to its properties window and set the "TargetServerVersion" value to the one you need (SQL Server 2012, in your case). Then you should be able to add your package to the project, for instance using "Add Existing Package" option in the project's pop-up menu.

Comment: Thanks Roger. In both my workstation and the target server, the SQL Server version is 2012, but when the package is imported somehow it gets automatically upgraded to version 8... How is that possible?

Comment: You are deploying it to SSISDB Store using the ISDeploymentWizard.exe? That's when conversion happens, and it's unavoidable AFAIK.